# Rotation and continuous writing of large log files with rsyslogd

Tags: linux, centos, logging, rsyslog, log-rotation

I have an extremely busy log file (let's call it `/var/log/service.log`) that is also frequently searched for troubleshooting reasons. Output to it is nearly continuous and 24/7. It probably puts out around 1-2 GB/day, but we need all of it.

Because `fgrep` of a large log file is impractically slow, there is a need to rotate frequently. I have `logrotate` set to run in `/etc/cron.hourly`, with an `hourly` directive and a size limit of `512M` or so.

This works as expected: the file is rotated from `/var/log/service.log` to `/var/log/service.log-20150810` or what have you. The problem is, the renaming is just a cosmetic change on the inode/directory entry, so `rsyslogd` continues writing to `/var/log/service.log-20150810` now and for some time, while the newly created `/var/log/service.log` sits empty. At some point, `rsyslogd` does decide to start writing to the new one instead, but I am not clear on its rhyme or reason for doing so.

Anyway, what I need is some way to "kick" `rsyslogd` to tell it to start writing to a new, pristine `/var/log/service.log` following the log rotation. Sending it SIGHUP doesn't seem to do the trick. Any ideas that don't involve potentially losing lots of log entries (i.e. restarting `rsyslogd`) would be appreciated!

(Side note: I gather that the `logrotate` naming scheme would lead to `/var/log/service.log.1` and whatnot, so, I'm a bit puzzled to see `/var/log/service.log-20150810` alongside it. Does `rsyslogd` do its own rotation internally, too? Are there some adverse implications to this?)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post your logrotate configuration file?

Comment: Sending SIGHUP is the right way, according to the man page. Consider filing a bug report.

Comment: So, I added 'killall -HUP rsyslogd' as a postrotate stanza to the logrotate configuration, and the crond log confirms that it runs, but it seems to have no effect; rsyslogd continues to write to the old log file. What else can be done here?

Comment: I have the exact same situation and cannot find a solution currently.

Comment: All I've been able to devise is to restart the rsyslogd service as part of the postrotate script.